# Cannot select HTML collection children

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When I use `console.log(jara.children);`, the console shows:

```
HTMLCollection []
  0: div#jarallax-container-2
  length: 1
  jarallax-container-2: div#jarallax-container-2
  __proto__: HTMLCollection
```

It shows length: 1. However, when I use `console.log(jara.children.length);` to print the collection length, it all shows `0`. It's kind of weird, I'm not quite familiar with HTML dom, can someone explain?

Edit:

```
var jaras = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div.jarallax"));
console.log(jaras);
jaras.forEach(function (jara) {
  console.log(jara.children.length);
});
```

Since I'm using https://github.com/nk-o/jarallax this package for parallax scrolling, the DOM is shown below:

[image]

Comment: can you please provide your code

Comment: console is showing a live collection (not a snapshot). Seems you are checking length before elements exist in that collection. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: problem updated

Comment: Still no way for us to reproduce problem from what is shown. We don't know where or when you run that code or how you initialize the plugin

Answer (score -1):

Try using `console.dir(jara)` it will give you more context as to what your are passing through your loop. You can always dig into it to see how you need to target the child element. I use console log along with dir many times.